# Computing affine springer fibers for SL(2)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, representation-theory

I am having some difficulties computing the affine springer fibers for SL(2), and understanding Examples 2.2.7 and 2.2.8 from Zhiwei's wonderful lecture notes ([here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.01451)).

Here is an example of my frustrations. I want to compute the affine Springer fiber of
$$\gamma = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & t^2 \\
t & 0 
\end{pmatrix}.$$

It's supposed to contain lattices $\Lambda \subset F \oplus F$ such that $t\mathcal{O} \oplus \mathcal{O} \subset \Lambda \subset \mathcal{O} \oplus t^{-1}\mathcal{O}.$

My attempt: Any rank 2 lattice is of the form $v_1\mathcal{O} \oplus v_2 \mathcal{O}$, where $v_1, v_2$ are 2d column vectors. According to this [thesis](https://scholarworks.umass.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1598&context=dissertations_2), we can perform row/column reductions on $v_1$ and $v_2$ so that

$$v_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ c_d \end{pmatrix}t^d + \cdots + \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ c_{e-1} \end{pmatrix} t^{e-1}, \quad v_2 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}t^e, \quad d \leq e.$$

I am somewhat willing to accept this fact for now. By applying $\gamma$ to this, I can work out what $v_1, v_2$ have to look like in order to be $\gamma$-invariant. One of the acceptable forms are

$$v_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ c_d \end{pmatrix}t^d, \quad v_2 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}t^{d+1}.$$

However, if I sub in $d = -2$, I obtain an invariant lattice outside of $\mathcal{O} \oplus t^{-1} \mathcal{O}$. The only thing I can see is wrong with my computations is that I have not yet imposed the condition for the relative dimension. Once I fix the correct degree $d$, I guess I can see how the affine Springer fiber is

Am I on the right track here? Or am I completely overthinking this? Is this generally the way to compute SL(2) affine springer fibers by hand?

Comment: Did you figure out? I would be interested to understand how to describe these fibers as well.

Comment: Dear @Nicolas Hemelsoet, Yes, I did figure it out!...using a rather slow brute-force method like the above. Here are my [notes](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12G4ks94jSsAIYFI8iNSdOa2yj1Zz8412/view?usp=sharing) on computing the affine springer fibers of A1, A2 and A3 type.  I tried to fix them up so that it is at least somewhat presentable. I hope it makes sense, or at the very least, gives you a taste of what the computations are like. You can probably just jump to section 1.1.

Comment: Let me know if I can help clarify anything!